# How can I dynamically populate start values in nls?

Tags: r, dynamic, nls

I'm feeding dynamic inputs into `nls()`, but I can't get the `start` argument to work. It seems I don't know how to feed it the right object. I need the object `vars` in the right structure to satisfy the `start` argument.

In this example, my starting values are stored in `vars`. I've tried reshaping it as well as messing with the object class using `as.vector`, `as.array` and `as.matrix`, among others, without success.

```
#need this package for acm.disjonctif()
library(ade4)

#get some fake data going for an ad measurement scenario
durta <- data.frame (  
    "impact"=c(150,150,350,50,150,150,  140,160,330,80,130,170)
  , "spend"= c(1000,1200,2300,500,1300,1000,  1900,1200,2000,500,1000,1400)
  , "adtitle"=c("zip","bang","boom","zip","bang","boom",  "zip","bang","boom","zip","bang","boom")
  , "network"=c("NBC","TNT","NBC","TNT","NBC","TNT",  "NBC","TNT","NBC","TNT","NBC","TNT")
  )

#making each element from network and adtitle into its own binary dimension
factors <- acm.disjonctif(durta[,3:4])

#getting rid of pesky byproducts
colnames(factors) <- gsub("network.","",gsub("adtitle.","",colnames(factors)))

#going to feed this to nls
input <- data.frame(cbind("impact"=durta$impact,"spend"=durta$spend,factors))

#also need to send these starting values
vars <- data.frame("var"=as.array(letters)[1:ncol(factors)],"start"=0)

#pasting a dynamic formula based on 'input' using as.formula works fine
#tried a similar solution for the starting values, failed 
fit <-  nls(   
  as.formula(paste(paste("impact ~ spend*(", paste(paste(vars[,1],"*"),noquote(colnames(input[3:ncol(input)])), collapse="+")),")"))
  , data=input
  , algorithm = "port"
  , start = vars
  #, start = c(a=.1,b=.3,c=0.3,d=-.9,e=.2)
  #          ^ this version works
)
```

If the `start` argument is satisfied, then I should get this (minor) error:

> Error in nlsModel(formula, mf, start, wts, upper) : 
>     singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates

When I replace the working static code with `var`, I get this:

> Error in nls(as.formula(paste(paste("impact ~ spend*(", paste(paste(vars[,  : 
>     parameters without starting value in 'data': e

I already put some sensible starting values in the static version to deal with that first error for this contrived example, but it still throws it. So be it. That's not my concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`start` needs to be a *named list*.  Thus

```
start = setNames(as.list(vars$start), vars$var)
```

seems to do what you want (takes the vector of values in `vars$start`, converts it to a list, and uses the corresponding elements of `vars$var` as its names).

For what it's worth, it looks like you could fit this particular model with `lm(impact/spend ~ ., data=input)` ...

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks, Ben Bolker. That's a dummy equation for illustration, but yes, I actually began using gam. I was too dense to figure out how to constrain the parameters, though, so I switched to nls using the 'port' algorithm.